# How to stop the actor when event source flow is closed?

Tags: java, playframework-2.6

I'm creating a EventSourceActor for each event source connection, and this actor create a eventsource flow. When the client calls `eventsource.close()`, I want the actor to be notified and close itself.

I've tried to use `Flow.watchTermination`, but the flow is not terminated when client disconnect.

I don't want to use Publisher, because I need a named `actorRef`, instead of a actor created with a publisher.

```
public class EventSourceActor extends AbstractActor {
    private final Materializer mat;
    private final SourceQueueWithComplete<JsonNode> sourceQueue;
    private final Source<JsonNode, NotUsed> eventSource;
    private final Flow<JsonNode, JsonNode, NotUsed> eventSourceFlow;

    private JsonNode testJson;

    @Inject
    public EventSourceActor(Materializer mat) {
        this.mat = mat;

        Pair<Sink<JsonNode, NotUsed>, Source<JsonNode, NotUsed>> sinkSourcePair = MergeHub.of(JsonNode.class, 16)
                .toMat(BroadcastHub.of(JsonNode.class, 256), Keep.both())
                .run(mat);
        Sink<JsonNode, NotUsed> hubSink = sinkSourcePair.first();
        this.sourceQueue = Source.<JsonNode>queue(bufferSize, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
                .to(hubSink)
                .run(mat);
        this.eventSource = sinkSourcePair.second();

        this.eventSourceFlow = Flow.fromSinkAndSourceCoupled(hubSink, eventSource)
                .watchTermination((n, stage) -> {
                    stage.thenAccept(f -> context().stop(self()));
                    return NotUsed.getInstance();
                });
```